# Elasticsearch NodeJs putIndexTemplate API

Tags: node.js, typescript, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm using elasticsearch 7.13.3 and I want to call the [put index template API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_indices_putindextemplate) from my typescript app. I'm using the package `"@elastic/elasticsearch": "7.13.0"` but I get error for the composition of the call.

From kibana I can execute without any error:

```
PUT _component_template/template-xxx2
{
  "template": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "double",
          "coerce": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT _index_template/index-template-xxx2
{
  "index_patterns": ["template-xxx2*"],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 2
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "created_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
        }
      }
    },
    "aliases": {
      "mydata": { }
    }
  },
  "priority": 600,
  "composed_of": ["template-xxx2"], 
  "version": 3,
  "_meta": {
    "description": "template-xxx2 description"
  }
}
```

and I want do the same from my node app.
The template creation it's ok:

```
void this.db.clientDb.indices.putTemplate({
  name: `template_${this.index}`,
  body: {
    mappings: {
      properties: {
        '@timestamp': {
          type: 'date'
        },
        id: {
          type: 'keyword'
        },
        value: {
          type: 'double',
          coerce: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But I can't find the correct overload for the `this.db.clientDb.indices.putIndexTemplate({` API.

**This gave me errors:** (no overloads match this call)

```
void this.db.clientDb.indices.putIndexTemplate({
  name: '',
  index_patterns: ["template-xxx2*"], // --> where should I put this property?
  body: {
    settings: {
      number_of_shards: 2
    },
    mappings: {
      _source: {
        enabled: true
      }
    },
    aliases: {
      mydata: {}
    }
  },
  priority: 500,
  composed_of: ['template-xxx2'], // --> where should I put this property?
  version: 3,
  _meta: {
    description: 'template-xxx2 description'
  }
});
```

I want to do [this latest script.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index templates have been overhauled in 7.8. The previous legacy endpoint was called `_template` and the new one is called `_index_template`.

You're mixing calls to the old and the new endpoint, i.e. `putTemplate` calls the old legacy endpoint and `putIndexTemplate` calls the new one.

Moreover, the whole template definition needs to go inside `body`, not at the top level of the call parameters.

So here is what you need to do. First, make this call to store the component template:

```
void this.db.clientDb.cluster.putComponentTemplate({
    "name": "template-xxx2",
    "body": {
      "template": {
        "mappings": {
          "properties": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "type": "date"
            },
            "id": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "double",
              "coerce": false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
})
```

Then store the index template with the following call:

```
void this.db.clientDb.indices.putIndexTemplate({
    "name": "index-template-xxx2",
    "body": {
      "index_patterns": ["template-xxx2*"],
      "template": {
        "settings": {
          "number_of_shards": 2
        },
        "mappings": {
          "_source": {
            "enabled": true
          },
          "properties": {
            "created_at": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
            }
          }
        },
        "aliases": {
          "mydata": { }
        }
      },
      "priority": 600,
      "composed_of": ["template-xxx2"], 
      "version": 3,
      "_meta": {
        "description": "template-xxx2 description"
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: I get the following error: ResponseError: invalid_index_template_exception: [invalid_index_template_exception] Reason: index_template [index-template-xxx2] invalid, cause [index template [index-template-xxx2] specifies component templates [template-xxx2] that do not exist]

Comment: You need to make sure to store the component template before the index template

Comment: Can I do a single creation merging it? I mean store the index template with the mapping without create the component template? Or in this case it doesn't work for the timeseries? (PS: your creation of component template give an error that miss the field 'index_patterns'. Should it is the same of index template?) thanks

Comment: I fixed the bug, `cluster.putComponentTemplate` instead of `indices.putComponentTemplate` for the component templates. my bad sorry